# Properly LogOut button React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

can't get the logout button to work properly. I'm using React and Firebase.
Here is a portion of the code from **App.js**, where the function was declared

*imports*

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { fire } from './fire';
import LogIn from './LogIn';
import Hero from './Hero';
import './App.css';
```

*declaration*

```
const handleLogout = () => {
  fire.auth().signOut();
};
```

And here is the code from the **Hero.js**, where the function is used

```
import React from 'react';
import Contact from "./components/Contact";

const Hero = (handleLogout) => {

    return(
        <section className="hero">
            <nav>
                <h2>Welcome</h2> 
                <button onClick = {handleLogout}>Log Out</button>
            </nav>
            <div id="contact-form">
                <Contact />
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}
export default Hero;
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you update your state hooks on logout? Like this: `fire.auth().currentUser.signOut().then(() => setLoggedIn(false));`

Comment: Did you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the `handleLogout` from `props` properly:

```
const Hero = ({handleLogout}) => {...}
```

Comment: i've tried it and it doesn't work, no errors, but no result as well

Comment: sorry, it works, i didn't write it properly, thanks

Comment: @AlexFurdui Glad I could help ;)